UnknownHostException: localhost.localstack.cloud on mac os
I am having the below exception while trying to run my integration tests in my Spring Boot application. I use Localstack and Amazon S3.
Related issue posted in github.
Caused by: software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: localhost.localstack.cloud
at app//software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException$BuilderImpl.build(SdkClientException.java:111)
at app//software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException.create(SdkClientException.java:47)
at app//software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.utils.RetryableStageHelper.setLastException(RetryableStageHelper.java:223)


It turns out that the issue is only happening in my Mac. It worked after I added this URL in my etc/hosts.
127.0.0.1       localhost.localstack.cloud


This is a one way to do it. I would like to share the documentation https://docs.localstack.cloud/references/network-troubleshooting/ and mention that
LocalStack only binds to IPv4 addresses (e.g. 127.0.0.1).
Please be aware of this if you have IPv6 enabled on your machine.
You can also alter the docker-compose.yml file by removing the IP and allowing it to connect to any address.
https://github.com/localstack/localstack/blob/master/docker-compose-pro.yml.
